# Using XSLT to transform one XML with one kind of Schema into another XML File with different Schema

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, schema, transformation

So I have this task of transforming one kind of XML file (with one Schema) into another XML file with different schema, and I need both files to be validated against their respective schemas. I did it (somehow) but I am interested if there is another way to do it, or this is fine.

My input XML schema location is http://www.example.org/example1 and output should be http://www.example.org/example2.

So what I did is that I used tag for both namespaces (xmlns:first nad xmlns:second) and i added this to my transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cus="http://www.example.org/Customer1"
xmlns:two="http://www.example.org/Customer2">
```

My output file is valid but it has xmlns:first="http://www.example.org/example1 in the root "description". Is that okay in the long term or should i search for a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you simply want to add `exclude-result-prefixes="first"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element so that result elements created by the XSLT do not show that namespace you only need to input element selection.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I was searching for EXACTLY that command!